# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'CategoryID'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, drop-down-menu

this is my controller action

```
 public ActionResult AddNewPost(string subName)
        {
          ViewBag.CategoryID = new SelectList(from c in db.Categories where c.Status == true select c, "CategoryID", "CategoryName");
          return View();
        }
```

in view i have populated dropdown as

```
<td>
    @Html.DropDownList("CategoryID", "-- Select --")
</td>
```

but when i try to access the drop down value in controller i get this error
"There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'CategoryID'."

Comment: Could you write Categories model?

Comment: Hi, were you able to figure this out?

Comment: Madu, see my post below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

view should be like this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(item =>Model.CategoryID,ViewBag.CategoryId as SelectList,"-- Select --")
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
//In Controller Action
public ActionResult AddNewPost(string subName)
{
    ViewBag.Cats = new SelectList(db.Categories
                             .Where(c=> c.Status)
                             .Select(c=> new {CategoryID = c.YourCatIdField, 
                                              CategoryName = c.YourCatNameField},
                             "CategoryID", "CategoryName");
    return View();
}

//In View
@Html.DropDownList("myCatId", 
                      (SelectList)(ViewData["Cats"]), "-- Select --")

//Controller
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddNewPost(string subName, int myCatId)
{
    //myCatId should bring the selected value here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
[httpGet]

public ActionResult AddNewPost(string subName)
        {
          ViewBag.CategoryID = new SelectList(from c in db.Categories where c.Status == true select c, "CategoryID", "CategoryName");
          return View();
        }


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddNewPost(string subName,ur model)
        {
          model.add(model);  
          ViewBag.CategoryID = new SelectList(from c in db.Categories where c.Status == true select c, "CategoryID", "CategoryName");
          return View();
        }
```

In Database Make CategoryId Allow nulls and in Model File Make it Has Nullable
Ex:
In Model

```
public int? CategoryId {get;set;}
```