# drop down list for using mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, html.dropdownlistfor

I was looking for a dropdownlistforcexample and found this is what I need [There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'CategoryID'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16728968/there-is-no-viewdata-item-of-type-ienumerableselectlistitem-that-has-the-key)

but I can't understand the "-- Select --" in the view page, if it means the select statement, well it's already mentioned in the controller, do I have to mention it again?

Comment: it's shown in in the dropdownlist as a default item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its the option label. The label that is shown when the page got rendered and no option is selected.

> optionLabelType: System.String
>   The text for a default empty item. This parameter can be null.

See: [enter link description here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492883(v=vs.118).aspx)