# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'ddlcontent'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

When I try to access the drop-down value in the controller I used to get this error "There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'ddlcontent'". Then now the issue that when I use the current view codes below, it displays nothing. Please tell me where am I missing it.

The links I tried checking are:
[There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'CategoryID'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16728968/there-is-no-viewdata-item-of-type-ienumerableselectlistitem-that-has-the-key)

[The ViewData item that has the key 'XXX' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366305/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-xxx-is-of-type-system-int32-but-must-be-o)

But none of them are helping so far.
View

```
      @model List<DemoWork.Models.Attendance>
      @using (Html.BeginForm("TakeDailyAttendance", "Trainer", FormMethod.Get))
 {

<table align="center">
    <tr>
        <th>

            @Html.Label("Event name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })

            @Html.DropDownList("dllcontent",new SelectList(ViewData.Model.Select(x=>x.Subject), ViewBag.dllcontent as SelectList), "-- select  --")
        </th>

        <th>
            <div class="col-lg-6">

                @Html.Label("StartDate", "From:", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                <input id="startdate" name="startdate" type="date" value="" class="form-control">
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-6">
                @Html.Label("enddate", "To:", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                <input id="enddate" name="enddate" type="date" value="" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </th>

        <th>

            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10" style="margin-top:25px;">

                <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>

        </th>
    </tr>
</table>




}
```

Controller

```
       [HttpGet]
       public ActionResult TakeDailyAttendance(string ddlcontent, DateTime? startdate, DateTime? enddate)
        {
        var listone = new List<string>();
        var nameqry = from n in db.Attendances
                      select n.Subject;

        listone.AddRange(nameqry.Distinct());

        ViewBag.ddlcontent = new SelectList(listone);

        var tb_teachers = db.Attendances.Where(x => x.StartDate >= startdate && x.EndDate <= enddate && x.Subject.Contains(ddlcontent) && x.Approval == "Going").ToList();

        return View(tb_teachers.ToList());
    }
```

Model

```
[Table("Attendance")]
public partial class Attendance
{
    public int AttendanceId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string TeacherId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string IdNumber { get; set; }

    [StringLength(200)]
    public string EmailId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [StringLength(200)]
    public string SchoolName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string District { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Province { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }

    public int? EventID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Subject { get; set; }

    [StringLength(300)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [StringLength(200)]
    public string Location { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string CourseId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string AttendaceStatus { get; set; }


    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Approval { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Pin { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: ``@Html.DropDownList("dllcontent", ViewBag.ddlcontent as SelectList)``

Comment: @Sajid I used your code but nothing happens when I click the search button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [asp-net-mvc-dropdown-list-from-selectlist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20243119/5519709):

> You are missing setting what field is the **Text** and **Value** in
>   the SelectList itself. That is why it does a `.ToString()` on each
>   object in the list. You could think that given it is a list of
>   `SelectListItem` it should be smart enough to detect this... but it is
>   not.

So in your case, you need to convert `List<String>` to `List<SelectListItem>` as follow:

```
ViewBag.ddlcontent = new SelectList(listone.Select(i=> new SelectListItem()
                                            {
                                                Text = i,
                                                Value = i
                                            }).ToList(),"Value" , "Text");
```

Comment: Yildiz,  I used your code but nothing happens when I click the search button

Comment: But your  question is not about click, did you managed to show items via dropdown with this code?

Comment: it does display items but still doesn't show search results.