# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'BlockHeight'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

So I've been running into this problem for a day now, I have tried a bunch of different things but it all doesn't seem to work.
What I've tried so far: [link one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26585495/there-is-no-viewdata-item-of-type-ienumerableselectlistitem-that-has-the-key), [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60722951/there-is-no-viewdata-item-of-type-ienumerableselectlistitem-that-has-the-key?rq=1).

It seems I am unable to post the selected item in the dropdown list to my controller. Every time I try I get the same error, `There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'BlockHeight'.`
I am still a beginner in ASP.NET so the error is not quite clear to me, but it looks like there is no `BlockHeight` key when I post the form although when I check in the debugger this key is present. To be clear, displaying the options in the dropdown list works fine, except the moment I submit the form the error above is thrown. I hope anyone can help me solve this problem.

**Context so you understand `vm.Heights` mentioned in the code snippets:**

```
CreateBlockViewModel vm = new CreateBlockViewModel();
        using (var BlokjeKwijt = new ContextFactory().CreateDbContext(null))
        {
            vm.Heights= BlokjeKwijt.Heights.ToList();
        }
```

Above correctly gets the data from the database, this is not the issue (I suppose)

**How I populate the SelectList:**

`ViewBag.BlockHeight = new SelectList(vm.Heights, "HeightId", "HeightName").ToList();`

What I have also tried:

```
ViewBag.Blockheight = new SelectList(vm.Heights.Select(i => new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = i.HeightName,
            Value = i.HeightId.ToString()
        }).ToList(), "Value", "Text");
```

and;

```
List<SelectListItem> slHeights = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (var height in vm.Heights)
        {
            slHeights.Add(
                new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = height.HeightId.ToString(),
                    Text = height.HeightName.ToString()
                }
            );
        }

        ViewBag.BlockHeight = slHeights;
```

**The ViewModel class**

```
public class CreateBlockViewModel
{
    public Block block { get; set; }
    public List<Color> colors { get; set; }
    public List<Height> heights { get; set; }
    //public IEnumerable<BlokjeKwijt.domain.Color> Colors { get; set; }
    //public IEnumerable<BlokjeKwijt.domain.Height> Heights { get; set; }

}
```

**Displaying the SelectList in my Razor view:**

`Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BlockHeight, ViewBag.BlockHeight as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })`

What I have also tried:

`@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BlockHeight, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.BlockHeight, "Selecteer hoogte", new { @class = "form-control" })`

and;

`@Html.DropDownList("BlockHeight", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.BlockHeight, new { @class = "form-control" })`

Comment: What is the view model?

Comment: Pls post viewmodel class and I can't see the code that you using to assign vm.Heights. Could you post it too pls?

Comment: @Serge I've updated my question. Hope you have what you need.